# How to animate progressbar color with Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I tried to create an animated progressbar where the progress is filling up animatedly and also it changes it's color depending on the final value of the progress.
The first part is working properly, but I can't figure out what is wrong with the color animation. What am I missing?

I used [flutter_rounded_progress_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_rounded_progress_bar) for displaying the progress bar.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_rounded_progress_bar/flutter_rounded_progress_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter_rounded_progress_bar/rounded_progress_bar_style.dart';

class MyLinearProgressIndicator extends StatefulWidget {
  final double currentProgress;
  final double height;
  final Color foregroundColor;
  final int duration = 500;

  MyLinearProgressIndicator({
    this.currentProgress,
    this.height = 5,
    this.foregroundColor = const Color(0xFFde8405)});

  @override
  _LinearProgressIndicatorState createState() =>
    _LinearProgressIndicatorState();
  }

class _LinearProgressIndicatorState extends State<MyLinearProgressIndicator> with 
SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController progressController;
  Animation<double> animation;
  Animation<Color> colorAnimation;
  CurvedAnimation curve;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    progressController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: widget.duration));

  curve = CurvedAnimation(parent: progressController, curve: Curves.ease);

  animation =
    Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: widget.currentProgress).animate(curve)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
  Color endColor;
  if (widget.currentProgress <= 30) {
    endColor = const Color(0xFFFF0000);
  } else if (widget.currentProgress <= 50) {
    endColor = const Color(0xFF00FF00);
  } else {
    endColor =const Color(0xFF0000FF);
  }
  colorAnimation =
    ColorTween(begin: widget.foregroundColor, end: endColor).animate(curve)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });

  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
    progressController.forward();
  });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
        child: Text("${widget.currentProgress.floor()}%",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 12,
              color: Color(0xFF333333))),
      ),
      Container(
        height: widget.height,
        width: 100,
        child: RoundedProgressBar(
          milliseconds: widget.duration,
          height: widget.height,
          style: RoundedProgressBarStyle(
              borderWidth: 0,
              widthShadow: 0,
              colorProgress: colorAnimation.value,
              backgroundProgress: Color(0xFFEBEBEB)),
          percent: animation.value,
        )),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    progressController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the current behavior?

Comment: The progress bar animates from 0 to widget.currentProgress properly, but the color is not changing

Comment: What is the color that it is showing you?

Comment: The original, widget.foregroundColor

Comment: based on the code above, I tried to create an example in DartPad but since I couldn't use the progressbar library there, I recreated something simmilar using simple widgets, and with those it works. The problem might be with the library I am using?

https://dartpad.dev/145410e1586efd627d7c1bd7caca34ec

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the current color value is being fetched from `Animation<Color>` with `colorAnimation.value`. A quick workaround here is to create a function that returns the color for ranges of values.

```dart
Color progressColor({required double value}) {
    if (value > 0.60) {
        return Colors.red;
    } else if (value > 0.30) {
        return Colors.orange;
    } else {
        return Colors.green;
    }
}
```

and set the Color to the ProgressIndicator

```dart
RoundedProgressBar(
  milliseconds: widget.duration,
  height: widget.height,
  style: RoundedProgressBarStyle(
    borderWidth: 0,
    widthShadow: 0,
    colorProgress: progressColor(animation.value),
    backgroundProgress: Color(0xFFEBEBEB)
  ),
  percent: animation.value,
)
```